# Angular + Яндекс API Карт

Tags: angularjs, яндекс-карты

Второй день пытаюсь заставить AngularJS показать Яндекс Карту с помощью [ya-maps](https://github.com/tulov/angular-yandex-map)

Причина по которой я не могу это сделать, возможно самая тривиальная, посему, прошу меня не винить, я впервые узнал что такое Angular позавчера, а Яндекс API открыл для себя вчера, и учитывая, что через месяц проект должен летать - времени на скрупулезное изучение нет.

Приведу свой код, буду премного благодарен, если вы его подправите так, чтобы он заработал.

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" xmlns:vml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ya-map-2.1.min.js"></script>


    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="map" class="w3-col s10 w3-dark w3-border">    
        <!-- 
         <ya-map ya-zoom="8" ya-center="[37.64,55.76]" style="width:400px;height:500px;"></ya-map>
         -->
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
console.log("script starts");

var myApp = angular
    .module('myApp', ['yaMap'])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
        console.log("In the controller");
        var _map;


        $scope.afterMapInit = function (map) {
            _map = map;
        };
        $scope.del = function () {
            _map.destroy();
        };

        console.log("After $scope ops");

        $scope.initialize = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: [50.5, 30.5],
                zoom: 8
            };
            ymaps.ready(function () {
                $scope.map = new ymaps.Map("map", mapOptions);
            })
        }
    });
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что у нестандартных тегов по умолчанию стоит `display:inline` - возможно значение отличается в разных браузерах. Поэтому не работало выставление размеров, и так как внутри не было текста - элемент схлопывался в ширину - 0, высоту - 0.

Далее, в приведенном скрипте из трех функций - не выполняется ни одна.

Посмотрите [страницу с примерами](http://tulov-alex.ru/2.1/)

```js
var myApp = angular
  .module('myApp', ['yaMap'])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    var _map;

    $scope.afterMapInit = function(map) {
      _map = map;
    };
    $scope.del = function() {
      _map.destroy();
    };

  });
```

```css
ya-map {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/tulov/angular-yandex-map/master/ya-map-2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="w3-col s10 w3-dark w3-border" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <ya-map ya-zoom="8" ya-center="[37.64,55.76]" ya-after-init="afterMapInit($target)"></ya-map>
  <button ng-click="del()">Удалить</button>
</div>
```